# Pandas: converting strings with "$" to float

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am a beginner trying to analyze a dataset of Congressional campaign funding sources but they are all string values with '$' in them. How can I quickly change every value into a numerical value?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJrGT.png)

Comment: You'll want to post the code here in the question even though you have it in the screenshot.

Comment: Hi Austin, could you give feedback on whether your issue was solved?

Answer (score 1):

```
states_table[dollar_columns] = states_table[dollar_columns].replace('[\$,]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Where `dollar_columns` is a list of the columns you want to convert. For instance:

```
dollar_columns = ['net_con', 'net_ope_exp']
```